# Topology of convergence in probability completely metrizable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(S,d)$ a complete separable metric space and $\mathcal{X}$ the set of $S$-valued random variables endowed with the topology of convergence in probability, i.e.

$$X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow}X \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0 :\mathbb{P}[d(X_n,X)>\epsilon] \rightarrow 0.$$

**Question:** Is $\mathcal{X}$ metrizable or even completely metrizable?

I know that this is true for $S=\mathbb{R}$, in this case one can use the metric $D(X,Y):=\mathbb{E}[1\wedge|X-Y|]$ on $\mathcal{X}$. But in general I can not think of any metric corresponding to the topology on $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: Why not $\mathbb E[1\wedge d(X,Y)]$? You will see that the proof is the same as in the case $S=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh, I will try this, thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you maybe know a reference for this result?

Comment: Kallenberg, “Foundations of Modern Probability” treats the case $S=\mathbb R$ in Chapter 4. I couldn't find any good reference for a general Polish space $S$, but the adaptation is anyway immediate.